# Как превратить массив с числами и объектами в строку JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, объекты, парсер

Добрый вечер! Мне нужно превратить массив, в котором есть числа, объекты и массивы с объектами, в строку и обратно на javascript. (никаких серверов, php, и.т.д.)
Пример объекта в моём массиве:

```
{ 
  file : "img/pekka.png", 
  x : random(100,900), 
  y : random(100,500), 
  w : 60, 
  h : 60, 
  angle : 0, 
  alpha : 1, 
  visible : true 
}
```

Пробовал это делать с помощью `JSON.stringify() и JSON.parse()`, но выдавало ошибку, что не может разпарсить. 
Если ничего не делать, то получается вот что:

```
7,10,1,3.3666666666666596,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],0,8,10,1,5.616666666666652,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],0
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!
Выдавало ошибку: `unexpected token f in JSON at position 1003`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` как раз этим и занимается, и в принципе единственный случай когда он выдает ошибку - в объектах есть циклические ссылки

Comment: Добавь в вопрос пример попытки использования указанных функций, и данные на которых выдавались ошибки

Comment: ок, сейчас добавлю

Comment: Эту ошибку JSON.stringify выдавала?

Comment: Ошибка - это хорошо, но нужен еще код, при выполнения которого эта ошибка происходит

Comment: Взял этот JSON и прогнал через JSON.stringify() , всё нормально, вернуло string с правильными значениями.

Comment: у меня тоже в JSON превращает нормально, а при JSON.parse ошибка

Comment: всё работает, добавил код на котором я проверял

Comment: Может быть код работать асинхронно и  JSON.parse() происходит раньше чем JSON.stringify().лишь в этом порядке выводится подобная ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё работает нормально, вот код на котором я проверял

```js
'use strict';
var obj = {
file : "img/pekka.png",
x : random(100, 900),
y : random(100, 500),
w : 60,
h : 60,
angle : 0,
alpha : 1,
visible : true
};

var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(typeof str);
console.log(str);
var strToObj = JSON.parse(str);
console.dir(typeof strToObj);
console.dir(strToObj);

function random(x, y) {
return x++, y++;
}
```